# Creating partly offscreen ncurses window

Tags: c++, windows, ncurses

I am interested in creating partly visible ncurses windows in terminal. When I make new ncurses window intersect right or bottom terminal window borders it shows correctly. E.g. of working code:

```
newwin(15, 12, LINES - 7, COLS - 6);
```

But when I try to make ncurses window intersect left/top borders of terminal nothing happens (ncurses window is not drawing). Full e.g. of not working code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    refresh();

    WINDOW* ncursesWindow = newwin(15, 12, -7, -6);
    wborder(ncursesWindow, '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*');
    wrefresh(ncursesWindow);

    int command = getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

The question is how to make the last code example work.

Answer (score 0):

That makes the window start off-screen.  The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h2-RETURN-VALUE) for `newwin` (see [source code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/c8bfb7efe41caf540b12b71b1eac5e26695daec4/ncurses/base/lib_newwin.c#L148)) and related functions says

> X/Open defines no error conditions.  In this implementation
>
> **`newwin`**
> will  fail if either of its beginning ordinates is negative, or if either the number of lines or columns is negative.

Although X/Open "defines no error conditions", that is the way most other implementations behave (checking Solaris SVr4 curses, NetBSD).  PDCurses appears to allow it.  Solaris xpg4 curses does something bizarre, but to see that you'd have to read the [source code](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/lib/libxcurses2/src/libc/xcurses/newwin.c#L76).

Comment: I edited question with full example of code. I filled window with border, but at the second example window is not showing.